# How can I prove that if g is a euclidean metric, then all diagonal values ​of the g matrix in any base are positive.

Tags: geometry

I'm studying euclidean metrics and I am not too sure if this argument is correct.
I think that if I calculate the determinant of each submatrix is enough, but I'm not sure.

Suppose that matrix is the matrix expression of the metric g, then we calculate the determinant of each submatrix, and as we know that all determinants are positive(because g is an euclidean metric), then all diagonal values are positive.
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & \dots & a_{1n} \\
a_{11} & a_{12} & \dots & a_{2n} \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots\\    
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \dots & a_{nn} \\    
\end{pmatrix}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your argument is not correct. For a matrix $A$ to be the Gram-matrix of an euclidean metric, you need $x^TAx > 0$ for all vectors $x \neq 0$. However, this does not mean that all subdeterminants need to be positive, for example
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 \\ -3 & 4\end{pmatrix}$$ induces an euclidean metric, even though one of the entries (and hence the determinant of the $1 x 1$ submatrix) is negative.

To show that the diagonal entries are positive in any basis $B = (b_1,b_2,\ldots, b_n)$, consider the scalar product $(b_i,b_i)$ for some $i$. As the metric is euclidean, it has to be positive. What has this product to do with your matrix?

Comment: Oh, I see. Each entry of the matrix is the scalar product $(b_i,b_i)$ for some $i$, right? Perfect then. Thanks!! ^^

Comment: Only the diagonal, but yes.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$e_i^T A e_i = a_{ii}$$